# How to check for file name too long error

Tags: go

While trying to create files, I am running into os.PathError because of "file name too long". I would like to handle this scenario to do something specific. How do I go about it, apart from inspecting error.Error which returns the string "file name too long"?

Comment: You don't apart from that. Comparing to the string value is the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is system dependent, but on unix systems the error value is [`syscall.ENAMETOOLONG`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/syscall/#ENAMETOOLONG)

```
if pe, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {
    if pe.Err == syscall.ENAMETOOLONG {
        log.Fatal("name really was too long")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but os.PathError does not expose the Err field of the struct PathError.

Comment: @GyanendraSingh: yes it does, [`PathError`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathError) contains an `Err` field with the original error value.